# onFocus spotlight effect on android

Tags: java, android, android-animation, android-resources, android-tv

I am trying to achieve the spotlight effect whenever an item in a recycler view is focused. I am attaching a image below to show what I mean. 
[image]

I have achieved something like this using a background drawable as shown below.
[image]

This is the code for drawable 
bg_glow.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
      <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <gradient
            android:startColor="#80e8eaed"
            android:gradientRadius="50dp"
            android:endColor="#00000000"
            android:type="radial" />
      </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

I have created a custom view that adds this drawable whenever the image is focused. Here is the code.

```
override fun onFocusChanged(gainFocus: Boolean, direction: Int, previouslyFocusedRect: Rect?) {
    super.onFocusChanged(gainFocus, direction, previouslyFocusedRect)
    if (gainFocus) {
        categorySpotlight.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.bg_glow)
        ivappCategory.strokeWidth = 2

    } else {
        categorySpotlight.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.transparent)
        ivappCategory.strokeWidth = 0
    }
}
```

Now there are a few problems with this:

1. radial gradient doesn't exactly looks like what I am trying to achieve.
2. It is not dynamic. I want to change the color of shadow based on dominant color in the image.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your gradient color based on the dominant color in the focused item's image.

If you can create the drawable programmatically, then you can also change the color of the shadow.

It's possible to create the drawable programmatically in android. See this :

```
public static GradientDrawable makeRadialGradient(int startColor, int endColor) {
  GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable(
  GradientDrawable.Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM, new int[]{startColor, endColor});
  gd.setGradientType(GradientDrawable.RADIAL_GRADIENT);
  gd.setGradientRadius(500.0f);
  gd.setGradientCenter(0.5f, 0.5f);
  return gd;
}
```

Now you can use this method with your custom colors & it'll give the gradient drawable (not the bitmap).
So if you want to use the gradient, then your target imageview background must be a gradient drawable (as it is now). Simply call the method:

```
makeRadialGradient(Color.parseColor("#D3D3D3"), Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
```

Now, If you want to make a gradient from the dominant color, then you can simply pass the color codes in the method and it will give you the gradient you want.

You have to change the values for the most perfect result.

Change the gradient radius, pivot points and type according to your preferences.

Comment: Not working at all. It's giving normal drawable, not what I needed. Thanks for reply btw.

Comment: Try reducing the radius to 100 or something else which gets your work done.

Comment: Not working. I just creates one oval which is not exactly what is needed. We need to create something like spotlight effect as shown in image above.